# Stripe checkout modal keyboard covers inputs and payment button on small devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic4

Edit:
This is for a hybrid mobile app made with Ionic 4.

On smaller devices (even smaller than the image attached) the inputs are covered by the keyboard on Android and iOS.  Lets focus on android for this question.

At this stage for this project I do not want to use stripe elements.

I have looked for ages on this and even contacted stripe support but have found no solution.
I have attached an image of the problem (it is worse on smaller phones) and also an image of how it looks if you open it in chrome on a mobile browser.

My options now seem to be:

1) Hack the css
2) Try and figure out how to get it to display like it does in the mobile browser (2nd image) as this is much more responsive to device size.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Legacy Checkout should always open up a new page/tab and fill the screen like in your 2nd screenshot. The only exception is if the page has been configured to be in "web app" mode.

Do you happen to have the following metatag on your site?

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

If so, if you remove it then Checkout should behave as expected.

Another solution is to use the new Checkout, which always opens up a new tab: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client

Comment: It is a hybrid mobile app.  It is using Ionic 4 and running in a mobile webview.  It does have that exact metatag but that is not going to help on Android if I remove it is it?  Not sure what it will do the rest of the app if I remove it...  Still learning.

Comment: I tried removing the tag in the iOS version but it does not seem to make a difference.  I wish the stripe iframe had scrolling turned on.

Comment: It actually does affect Android as well. The idea is that if you set up web app mode for one browser you probably meant to have it for all browsers.